# cannot run pyinstaller executable of a flask server. ValueError: Can't find a dictionary for language 'ru'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to put a simple flask server into executable by using `pyinstaller -F server.py` command

When running the exe file, I obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "transform.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "convert.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 200, in __init__
  File "pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 280, in choose_dictionary_path
  File "pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 144, in lang_dict_path
ValueError: Can't find a dictionary for language 'ru'. Installed languages: []. Try installing pymorphy2-dicts-ru package.
[18156] Failed to execute script server
```

Already tried to `pip install pymorphy2-dicts-ru`, it didn't help

Below are the logs of `pyinstaller -F server.py`

```
96 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
97 INFO: Python: 3.6.8
97 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
103 INFO: wrote C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\server.spec
118 INFO: UPX is not available.
122 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\hack\\code\\nlp-server',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\hack\\code\\nlp-server']
139 INFO: checking Analysis
140 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
140 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
145 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
169 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3178 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3265 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3268 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
3440 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\server.py
4658 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
4659 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib'
7000 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.m
oves.py'.
7477 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
7478 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
10016 INFO: Processing module hooks...
10017 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
10031 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10034 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
10034 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10035 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10038 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
10038 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10146 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10148 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
10149 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10247 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10249 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'test'
10249 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10827 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10830 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10832 INFO: Excluding import of pytest from module numpy._pytesttester
10833 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10835 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
10835 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11162 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
11219 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
11462 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
11464 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
11465 INFO: Excluding import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
11466 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12062 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.command.easy_install
12062 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.package_index
12065 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.depends
12065 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.package_index
12066 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12067 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12068 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12121 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12123 INFO: Excluding import of numpy from module setuptools.msvc
12199 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
12231 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
12237 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
12238 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
12250 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
13139 INFO: Looking for eggs
13139 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
13139 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
13150 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\build\server\warn-server.txt
13296 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\build\server\xref-server.html
13324 INFO: checking PYZ
13325 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
13326 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\build\server\PYZ-00.pyz
14479 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\build\server\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
14505 INFO: checking PKG
14505 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
14505 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
20039 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
20043 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
20043 INFO: checking EXE
20043 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
20043 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
20044 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\pc\Desktop\hack\code\nlp-server\dist\server.exe
20060 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

code of the server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

from transform import transform_text

server = Flask(__name__);

@server.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send():
    print("POST /send request")

    # obtaining passed args
    fname = request.json['fname']
    text = request.json['text']

    # updating the text
    text = f"{transform_text(text, 'Masc', fname)}"

    # sending back updated text
    return jsonify({'text': text})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', debug=True)
```

`tranform_text()` function uses pymorphy to change sentences from 1st person form ("I play") to 3rd person form("He/She plays")

So, is there any way to make the executable work?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem of the package ;pymorphy2_dicts_ru;. Files from the data directory are not copied to the bundle.

To solve the problem, you need to perform two steps:

1. Add the data directory to the pyinstaller spec file:

   ```
   ...
   # pymorph data
   import pymorphy2_dicts_ru
   pymorph_data = pymorphy2_dicts_ru.get_path()

   a = Analysis(['main.py'],
            pathex=['.'],
            binaries=[],
            datas=[(pymorph_data, 'pymorphy2_dicts_ru/data')],
            hiddenimports=[],
            hookspath=[],
   ...
   ```
2. Set the path to the data directory in the code before import the pymorphy2 module (to main.py for example):

   ```
   ... 
   if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
       os.environ["PYMORPHY2_DICT_PATH"] = str(pathlib.Path(sys._MEIPASS).joinpath('pymorphy2_dicts_ru/data'))
   ...
   ```

Comment: This seems like a messy solution, but it worked perfectly for me. If anybody figures out a simpler approach that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In `analyzer.py` there is a recommendation that might work:

```
Alternatively (e.g. if you have your own precompiled dictionaries),
either create ``PYMORPHY2_DICT_PATH`` environment variable
with a path to dictionaries, or pass ``path`` argument
to :class:`pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer` constructor::

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer(path='/path/to/dictionaries')
```